# Laravel Eloquent hacer where sobre relación with()

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy haciendo una consulta donde traigo una lista de envíos y a la ves sus respectivas relaciones con otras dos tablas (remitentes y destinatarios), esto lo hace sin problemas, me trae mi lista de envíos con respectivas relaciones

```
 $shipments = Shipment::->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                        ->with('remitent')
                        ->with('destinatary')
                        ->paginate(10);
```

Pero no se como hacer con Eloquent hacer un where sobre una de las relaciones, para una búsqueda necesito filtrar por el nombre de del remitente.

En SQL seria algo así.

```
SELECT shipments.*, remitents.*, destinataries.*
    FROM shipments 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN remitents  ON remitents.id = shipments.remitente_id
    LEFT OYTER JOIN destinataries  ON destinataries.id = shipments.destinatary_id
    WHERE remitents.name LIKE "%Luis%" /* <- esto es lo que no se como hacer con Eloquent */
```

Cuando se hace por búsqueda el nombre no esta en los shipments, esta en le relación del remitente

Necesito que el objeto me lo devuelva como lo la primera consulta. Que el Objeto Shipment tenga los datos del remitente y destinatario como objetos:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 14,
      "tracking_number": 16808250909114,      
      "remitent_id": 14,
      "destinatary_id": 14,     
      "remitent": {
        "id": 14,
        "mail": "you@example.com",
        "name": "Luis",
      },
      "destinatary": {
        "id": 14,
        "mail": "me@example.com",
        "name": "Juan",

      }
    },
    ...
]
```

Ya lo hice con Query Builder, pero me devuelve todas la columnas en un solo objeto, no me separa lo que es del remitente ni del destinatary.

Alguien ha hecho algo similar? De antemano Gracias, saludos!

Comment: Si entiendo bien, solo quieres obtener los Shipment que tengan un remitente donde el nombre sea Luis. Si es así  [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) es lo que te serviría.

Comment: puedes hacerlo con `DB::raw` ejemplo: `$results = DB::select( DB::raw("select * from tables inner join table_2.........") );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza whereHas para hacer un filtro en la relación, también puedes hacer el like en su función anónima:

```
// $userName = 'Luis';

// ...

->whereHas('remitent', function ($query) use ($userName) ({
    $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$userName}%");
})
```